# How to iterate over the letters in a string ignoring blank spaces?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, iteration

I have been searching for this a while now and I can't find an answer that helps me.

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    list.append(string)
return list
```

If e.g the string contains blank spaces it will obviously do extra strings

e.g if `string = ' Hello '`

Output is

```
[' Hello ', ' Hello ', ' Hello ', ' Hello ', ' Hello ', ' Hello ', ' Hello ']
```

Instead of

```
[' Hello ',' Hello ',' Hello ',' Hello ',' Hello ']
```

If the string was `' Test String '`, the spaces in the middle should also be ignored, giving a list of length `10`.

Comment: for blank spaces add a test condition `for i in string  if i.strip() list.append(string)` or  strip the string which will remove leading and trailing while spaces `for i in range(string.strip())`

Comment: I'm new with `Python` but what if you change `for i in range(len(string)):` > `for i in string.replace(" ",""):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore spaces, you could use the following code. Note that I've changed the variable name from `list` to `lst`, as using `list` shadows the python builtin. Instead of iterating over the indexes of the length of the string, we just iterate over the letters in the string.

```
string = ' Test String '
lst = []

for letter in string:
    if letter != ' ':
        lst.append(string)

print(lst)
```

**Output:**

```
[' Test String ', ' Test String ', ' Test String ', ' Test String ', ' Test String ', ' Test String ', ' Test String ', ' Test String ', ' Test String ', ' Test String ']
>>> len(lst)
10
```

**Alternatively, as a list-comprehension:**

```
>>> [string for c in string if c.strip()]
[' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ']
```

This works by iterating over the letters in the string and checking if each character with whitespace stripped is the empty string or not.

Answer (score 0):

Doing simply

```
lis = [string for c in string if c != ' ']
```

will output

```
[' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ',
 ' Test String ']
```